# Save desktop configuration (multi-monitor and/or external monitor)

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, resolution

My laptop using a 1920x1080 resolution for the desktop. When I load Visual Studio or Google Chrome or something else, I expect the window layout to be "just so".

Every now and then I would like to connect the laptop to an external monitor and extend my desktop to the 2nd monitor (or "project" in Windows 8.1 parlance). Alternatively, I might connect to a projector which has a lower resolution (say 1024x768) and after disconnecting, I find that all my icons bunched up in the upper left of the screen. Also, Visual Studio now has a crazy windows layout and it takes ages to restore everything.

I'd like to set everything up then save the desktop and window layout as "LAYOUT-A". Then connect to the external monitor, set everything up again and save that as "LAYOUT-B", and so on. Then when I switch on the laptop, I can just load in LAYOUT-A, B or C.

Is this possible? Windows 8.1 here.

Comment: [Program to save visible windows' locations and later restore the layout](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1816)

Comment: [How to Save and restore desktop icon layout](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-save-restore-desktop-icon-layout-3421846/)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Ok, thanks. About to give IconRestorer a go...

Answer (score 0):

Using Nirsoft's Multimonitortool (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) you can create batch files for each configuration using the /MoveWindow command line switch. May take a little work to set up, but it's free and very configurable.